# When does Vue store data during the created() process?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to store data with a created() method and then access it with a mounted() method but the data doesn't seem to be stored until after. Is there a way to do this?

I have setup a test. In created() I run

```
created() {
            this.getCountriesList();
        },
```

This does an axios call to get the countries and then saves them to data

```
getCountriesList() {
                axios.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all?fields=name')
                .then(axiosResult => this.countrydata = axiosResult.data) 
            },
```

Then in mounted() which I was led to believe comes next I am calling my method

```
mounted() {
            this.countryFilteredList()

        }
```

The method is just a console.log

```
countryFilteredList() {
                console.log(this.countrydata);
            },
```

This returns

```
[__ob__: Observer]
length: 0
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(0), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array
```

but if I create a button that on click calls the same countryFilteredList() I get this

```
(250) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
[0 … 99]
[100 … 199]
[200 … 249]
```

Is there a way I can get this data loaded in mounted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't: fetching data from an endpoint is **asynchornous in nature** and the `mounted()` lifecycle hook does not guarantee that the data has been fetched. What you should do is simply place a watcher on `this.countrydata` and then act upon it once it is populated.

```
data: function() {
    return {
        countryData: []
    };  
},
created() {
    this.getCountriesList();
},
methods: {
    getCountriesList() {
        axios.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all?fields=name')
        .then(axiosResult => this.countrydata = axiosResult.data);
    }
},
watch: {
    countryData: function(data) {
        if (data.length) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
}
```